# Remove Item from ListView Automatically after using AlarmManager

Tags: android, listview, alarmmanager

I am developing an SMS application were numbers and text message are predefined in a list and when a timer matches the saved time, an SMS is sent to the numbers.

I am able to send messages (through AlarmManager), but how can I remove that item from the saved list automatically (i.e remove numbers from list after message is sent)?

Comment: Gentlemen's use ContentProviders for the lists and change notifications to manage them, but it's complex and not very intuitive solution. I wonder if there's a simpler one, so now we both are wating for the answer;)

Comment: Why cant you remove the sent item from the list. And if the same list is shared with your adapter just say notify data set changed. Considering you know which text item to be removed, as you are sending the same through SMS.